# Facebook PHP SDK 5.0 version returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing in firefox

Tags: php, sdk, facebook-oauth

Facebook PHP SDK 5.0 version returned an error:

> Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state"
>   missing in firefox.

I am getting the access token in chrome, but not with firefox. Any ideas?

Facebook App Domains are set to `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`
Facebook Site URL is `http://www.domain.com`
oAuth redirect url is `http://www.domain.com/fb-callback.php`

Comment: It would be better (for future reference) to include actual version of SDK instead of 'latest'.

Comment: Sorry... It is PHP SDK 5.0